# Will "kill -SIGTERM" stop "tail -f"?

Tags: 12.04, bash, scripts, kill

Just as the title says, Google gives me nothing and I can't test it on this server.

The command as is follows:

`tail -f <file> | fgrep --line-buffered "string" | sed -u 's/stuff//g' >> output.log`

Do I need to use `kill -SIGTERM <PID>` or `kill -SIGKILL <PID>` to stop a `tail -f`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- SIGTERM sends a signal to the command and will tell the command to stop itself. If there is a need to clean-up files due to the kill the command can do that.
- SIGKILL sends a signal to the init system. The command itself does not get even told it is going to get killed.

So you can use both; but SIGTERM should be preferred (it is more graceful).

> Will “kill -SIGTERM” stop “tail -f”?

Yes, it will. On Linux tail acts on SIGTERM.

Comment: Roboman1723: This's a wrong answer. @Rinzwind: Why do you say `SIGKILL` send a signal to the init system?

Comment: Will `SIGTERM` stop `tail -f` is all I really care about for now. If it does then I'm okay.

Comment: @cuonglm  well it got me a hat :D

Answer (score 1):

You don't even have to use `SIGTERM`. `tail` listens for `SIGINT` and `SIGQUIT` too. I'm not sure if there's any difference between signals (it's all specific to `tail`) but any of these would be better than `SIGKILL`.

It's quite easy to test too:

```
$ tail -f /dev/null > /dev/null &
[1] 26599
$ kill -SIGINT $!
[1]+  Interrupt               tail -f /dev/null > /dev/null
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm essentially trying to emulate a service with this script so at midnight i stop and restart it. I wouldn't want a bunch of interrupted processes hanging around. Good to know though.

Comment: INT and QUIT: keystrokes are different (control c and control \) and QUIT created a core dump. That's all.